# JMeter aggregate report does not aggregate in non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter, aggregate

I have a JMeter test plan which is running two thread groups, with each thread group containing a controller and HTTP cookie manager. The controller is a custom controller, but I don't think this should affect JMeter's output.

Outside the two thread groups, I have an Aggregate Report component. Here is a screenshot of my TestPlan:

[image: test plan screenshot]

If I run the test in GUI mode, as you would expect, the Aggregate Report creates an.... aggregate report. That is, the results are aggregated on my test/sample labels, and I get one row for each test, and a range of attributes, as below:

[image: Aggregate report in the gui window]

I also have configured this Aggregate Report component to output to a file, by entering a filename in the "Filename" section, and pressing the "Configure" button and checking the attributes I'd like to be output (I've kept it simple for now with just the label, elapsed time and response code).

[image: Aggregate report config with the filename and attributes]

When I run my test from non-gui mode, this output file is the only way to view the results. However, the output file is rather useless and it does not aggregate the results, but instead gives me output similar to the usual jtl output, i.e. it doesn't aggregate the results at all. Pretty useless. Here is the top few lines of my output file, you can clearly see they are not aggregated:

```
778,HRLogin,200
426,HRLogin,200
784,HRLogin,200
...
```

So, the obvious question, am I doing something wrong here? Why is my aggregate report output not an aggregate report? Surely JMeter has a way for producing aggregate output in non-gui mode, without me adding any plug-in or extensions. For the record I need to script this process at some point, so opening a JTL in gui mode is not acceptable, I need this entire process to occur within non-gui JMeter and scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values you see in the Aggregate Report GUI are **calculated** from the raw data which is stored in the .jtl file.

If you need to make the process unattended, depending on metrics you need to obtain here are the options:

1. Since JMeter 3.0 there is a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which contains some tables and charts. You can either generate a dashboard from existing results file or make it a part of your test. See [Generating Reports](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) chapter for the relevant commands.
2. Another way to get basic HTML report is running JMeter via [Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) or [Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) - in both cases you'll get test output like:

   [image: JMeter HTML Report.]

   See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details on configuring a JMeter test run through Ant and/or Maven. There is a number of pre-defined .xsl stylesheets in "extras" folder, you can take whatever you like and customize if needed.
3. You can also consider running your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool, it provides [**interactive** console and web-based reporting and has few more options to export test results](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#BlazeMeter-com-Reporting-Service).

Comment: Thanks, I've since solved it using the CMDRunner which happened to come with my install anyway. I'll mark this as an answer anyway.