# Can't generate Aggregate Report with Apache JMeter

Tags: java, logging, jmeter, load-testing

I've been having every issue under the sun with Apache JMeter which seems to be extremely poorly developed, being incompatible with everything from the latest version of Java SE to itself even!

I began with errors being thrown simply as a result of the (native) dark theme which came with the app...

After working through those, I'm now trying to produce an Aggregate report for my load test Thread Group which I run from the command line using a PowerShell wrapper which simply takes in some parameters and passes them as variables to the JMX (duration, loop count, etc).

The Aggregate report is generating and saving a CSV similar to the summary report though... not showing percentiles and throughput etc. rather every single request in its own row.

Upon further reading, I need to continue to manually process the results generated from the singular report JMeter is able to produce (really?), however, following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042847/jmeter-aggregate-report-does-not-aggregate-in-non-gui-mode) I add another command to generate the Aggregate from the csv summary and it throws some more abstract errors which appears to be a result of a Java version conflict (according to [this pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294826/error-while-generating-report-in-apache-jmeter-5-4-1-tgz)t)

Everyone suggests that Java SE 17 is the issue, so I uninstall Java 17 and install an earlier version people suggest is working (v16) and now I can't even load the csv into the program...
[image]

EDIT: I removed the dark theme once again and that error is fixed now.

I just want to generate an Aggregate report after my load test... how can I achieve this seemingly simple task in the ever so complicated and janky JMeter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the consequence of [JMeter Bug 65300](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300)

If you cannot use Java 8 (as the errors you're getting are specific to Java 9 and higher) you could amend [line 112 of your `jmeter.bat` startup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) to look like:

```
set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Also be aware that it's possible to generate the CSV version of the Aggregate Report using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) as:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/test/result.csv --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. Your other posts have helped me as well! I ultimately downgraded my Java SE version to 16 which seemed to do the trick. JMeter is quite frustrating. Thanks again!